# sqlite Include type in column declaration

Tags: database, sqlite

Is there a reason to include column types in CREATE TABLE statements in sqlite given that sqlite is not statically typed anyway? Please provide an example to illustrate if possible?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite uses the declared column types for [type affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity), where values are automatically converted, if possible.